# Does the font size stay the same or become smaller (bigger) when viewed on different screen resolutions (Responsive website)

Tags: fonts, web, size, responsive

I'm a designer and I'm designing a responsive website mockups (applied on iMac, Macbook pro and iphone). The trouble I'm having is when I scale the size from the iMac screen resolution to the Macbook screen resolution, the font size changes, and I don't know if it should change like that or should it stay the same size as for the iMac screen. Thank you.

Comment: You don't know if it should? Do you want it to?

Comment: Pixels won't, cm will, in will, percentage won't..

Comment: I don't know if there's a rule for that, if the rule says it stays the same then I'll keep the same size and the way around.

Comment: Have you tested some code? What happens? What would you like to happen?

Comment: I don't know much about coding, I'm just making mockups and I want to know what happens to the font when the website is actually coded to be responsive. Like in the style.css the font will always be a certain size, but when you see it on different devices, is the size different or same?

Comment: If my answer solved it, don't forget to tick the check on its left :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible.
It all depends on the actual code written by the web designer.

For example, font size written in:

- Pixels: will change depending on pixel size of screen.
- Inches: 'should' remain inches. The same (Same for Cm).
- Percentage: will change to be the given percentage of the given screen.
  And so forth.